# C++ compiler error definition of implicitly declared

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

Hello everyone having anissue with my code today. I have created a program calculating area of square circle and rectangle. With a base class of shape. Where the UML has shape as the abstract class with public area():double, getName():string,and getDimensions:string, rectangle derived from shape with protected height, and width, and a public rectangle(h:double, w:double), followed by a derived square from rectangle with just a public square(h:double), and finally a circle derived from shape with a private radius, and a public circle(r:double).
So far have gotten far in my code yet in my shape.cpp file am getting an error on line 10 that says shape.cpp:10: error: definition of implicitly-declared 'constexpr shape::shape()'
 shape::shape()

here is a link to my complete code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0eedd7719a34655488fb

shape.cpp file:

```
#include "shape.h"
#include "circle.h"
#include "rectangle.h"
#include "square.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

shape::shape()
{

};
```

your help is appreciated

Comment: You haven't declared the `shape` constructor inside the `shape` class definition.

Comment: Entire rectangle.cpp is redeclaring its header?

Comment: thank you both I made the recommended changes and now am getting an error that says redefinition of shape::shape on line 10 of shape.cpp

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the `shape()` constructor to your class declaration like this:

```
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

using namespace std;

class shape
{
public:

    shape();
    virtual double area()=0;

    virtual QString getName()=0;
    virtual QString getDimensions()=0;

    virtual~shape(){}

};
#endif
```

You can then create the definition in shape.cpp like this:

```
shape::shape()
{

}
```

without a semicolon at the end.

Comment: okay so I went ahead and removed semicolon like above and I corrected my shape.h so that is now reads as follows